# Abstract class and mandatory methods of childs?

Tags: java, oop, interface, abstraction

I have this abstract base class and each of it's childs should have a specific mandatory function but slightly different. Is this possible using the abstract class or should I be using an interface for this?

I will be using the structure like this

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    //Mandatory method
    Public void sound()
    {

    }
}

public class Cat extends Animal
{
    public void sound()
    {
        System.out.println("Miauw");
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animal
{
    public void sound()
    {
        System.out.println("Woof");
    }
}

//I will put all these child objects in a List<Animal> and need to call these methods.

for (Animal a : animalList)
{
    a.sound();
}
```

How would one go about this structure? I have to add that I am using an abstract class because there are plenty of identical methods that need to be shared among the child classes. Just some of the methods need to be different from each other but mandatory and accessible from the base class.

Comment: Which Java version do you use?

Comment: Your access modifiers are not valid for Java.

Comment: general tip use interface always, abstract class is used only when there is a same implementation of some methods around different subclasses

Comment: Yeah, I just wrote it inside the textbox here for a quick example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for:

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    //Mandatory method
    abstract public void sound();
}
```

But also look at other users advices:

- use lowercase for method names
- the keyword `public`always goes in lowercase
- use interfaces if your Animal class hasn't common code for all children classes

Comment: Why method name starts with capital letter? This is against Java code standard.

Comment: I copied his example.

Comment: Thanks, I got an error when doing this but had to get rid of the curly braces. This was exactly what i was looking for. I started learning C# and i'm still using c sharps naming conventions when I am not paying attention and put things down on paper in a hurry.

Answer (score 1):

Both an abstract class and an interface would work in this case. The times when you'd want to use an abstract class is when there are common methods and data that you want shared among all subclasses. Such as, if `Animal` had a weight variable, and each subclass sets that variable.

NOTE: In an abstract class, any methods that you don't want to implement, you must declare as abstract. See how I modified `Sound()` below. Also, a bonus tip is that the standards say that method names should start with a lowercase letter, so I changed `Sound` to `sound`.

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    private int weight;

    public void setWeight(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    //Mandatory method
    abstract public void sound();
}

public class Cat extends Animal
{
    public Cat(int weight) {
        this.setWeight(weight);
    }

    public void sound()
    {
        System.out.println("Miauw");
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animal
{

    public Dog(int weight) {
        this.setWeight(weight);
    }

    public void sound()
    {
        System.out.println("Woof");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for Java's `abstract` modifier. [The official Java Documentation contains more specific information about `abstract` and `final` here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html).

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    // Mandatory method with no "default" implementation.
    public abstract void Sound();

    // Optional method with a default implementation.
    public void Move() {
        // some actions here
    }

    // Optional method with a fixed implementation (it can't be changed in a child class).
    public final void Eat(Food food) {
        // some actions here
    }
}
```

Comment: Why all method name starts with capital letter? This is against Java code standard.

Comment: I was just using the same style as the person asking the question.

Comment: And i was just typing a example quickly and learned most of my programming with C#, hence the uppercase method names.

Answer (score 0):

you should use interface in this case  because you are not defining any method, if you only want to provide declaration interface is ok for that

if you use abstract class you overhead by overriding the method and define it again

Comment: I am using the abstract method as intended. I just needed to put an example here, all childs need a lot of methods that are exactly the same but some need slightly different methods but mandatory ones.

Comment: if you want to give definition of mandatory method also then its ok